# FFMPEG changes speed when concat 2 or more different videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this code

```
ffmpeg   -y  -re -i "/myvideos/countdown10.mp4"   -re -i "/myvideos/video_218.mp4"  -re -i "/myvideos/video_220.mp4"   -re -i "/myvideos/video_221.mp4"  -re -i "/myvideos/video_222.mp4"   -re -i "/myvideos/countdown10.mp4"  -re -i '/myvideos/watermark.png'  -filter_complex " [0:v] [0:a]   [1:v] [1:a]   [2:v] [2:a]   [3:v] [3:a]   [4:v] [4:a]   [5:v] [5:a]  concat=n=6:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [vv] [a]; [vv][6:v]overlay=W-w-0:0[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  -preset veryfast -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -y -s 1280x720  -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://server/live/5fa3731d4f8a6_159
```

the problem is, when I run it the process speed is a lot faster then the videos length, so I got disconnected from my livestream before the live finishes.

I guess it is something related to the bit rates.

also I notice depends on what video is transcoding the speed floats between 0.9x and 3.7x

[frame= 4481 fps= 76 q=-1.0 Lsize=   16857kB time=00:03:13.21 bitrate= 714.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=393 speed=3.29x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKGdG.png)

Edited:

Complete log file:

```
avideo@ubuntu:~$ ffmpeg    -re -i "/var/www/gdrive/htdocs/YouPHPTube-Encoder/videos/videosListToLive/countdown10.mp4"   -re -i "/var/www/gdrive/htdocs/YouPHPTube-Encoder/videos/videosListToLive/192.168.1.4/video_222.mp4" -filter_complex " [0:v] [0:a]   [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"   -preset veryfast  -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -y -s 1280x720 -ar 44100  -f flv rtmp://encoder.gdrive.local/live?p=f321d14cdeeb7cded7489f504fa8862b/5fa3731d4f8a6_160
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/gdrive/htdocs/YouPHPTube-Encoder/videos/videosListToLive/countdown10.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 122 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 83 kb/s, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 10240 tbn, 10 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 35 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/gdrive/htdocs/YouPHPTube-Encoder/videos/videosListToLive/192.168.1.4/video_222.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 37 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 26 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/16/2018.
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/16/2018.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat:in0:v0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] using SAR=1/1B time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://encoder.gdrive.local/live?p=f321d14cdeeb7cded7489f504fa8862b/5fa3731d4f8a6_160':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 5 fps, 1k tbn, 5 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
[flv @ 0x5645453ae580] Failed to update header with correct duration. 49.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=751 speed=1.33x
[flv @ 0x5645453ae580] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=  205 fps=6.7 q=-1.0 Lsize=     250kB time=00:00:40.58 bitrate=  50.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=762 speed=1.33x
video:164kB audio:53kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 15.473391%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] frame I:2     Avg QP: 4.62  size: 10450
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] frame P:58    Avg QP:10.06  size:  1457
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] frame B:145   Avg QP:11.12  size:   427
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] consecutive B-frames:  4.9%  1.0%  4.4% 89.8%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] mb I  I16..4: 91.4%  2.8%  5.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] mb P  I16..4:  8.4%  0.4%  0.1%  P16..4:  2.0%  0.3%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:88.6%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.9%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 4.7%  skip:94.0%  L0:33.9% L1:63.4% BI: 2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] 8x8 transform intra:5.5% inter:24.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 4.7% 22.9% 19.5% inter: 0.2% 4.2% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] i16 v,h,dc,p: 94%  4%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 18% 37%  3%  2%  3%  2%  2%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 38% 20% 21%  5%  3%  4%  3%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] i8c dc,h,v,p: 78%  8% 12%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] Weighted P-Frames: Y:20.7% UV:20.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5645453b7a80] kb/s:32.64
[aac @ 0x564545421540] Qavg: 61548.156
avideo@ubuntu:~$
```

Also here is a video where you can see the process

https://tutorials.avideo.com/video/102/ffmpeg-changes-speed-when-concat-2-or-more-different-videos

this live should have exactly 40 seconds but finishes before then that

also look at this time position https://tutorials.avideo.com/video/102/ffmpeg-changes-speed-when-concat-2-or-more-different-videos?t=12

the speed changes from speed=0.9 to speed=1.9

[speed=0.9 to speed=1.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcNZw.png)

**EDITED 2:**

I tried the FPS command as suggested and still the problem

```
avideo@ubuntu:~$ ffmpeg    -re -i "http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/index.m3u8?token=eyJzYWx0IjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvMTkyLjE2OC4xLjRcL1lvdVBIUFR1YmVcLyIsInRva2VuVGltZU91dCI6IjIxNjAwIiwiZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJfWVBUdW5pcWlkXzVmODBjNTQ3NDIxMDU3LjI0MDU2MDE1IiwidGltZSI6MTYwNTI4MzExN30="   -re -i "http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5fa3f4e37ffb65.33430678_720.mp4?token=eyJzYWx0IjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvMTkyLjE2OC4xLjRcL1lvdVBIUFR1YmVcLyIsInRva2VuVGltZU91dCI6IjIxNjAwIiwiZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJfWVBUdW5pcWlkXzVmYTNmNGUzN2ZmYjY1LjMzNDMwNjc4IiwidGltZSI6MTYwNTI4MzExN30="   -re -i '/var/www/gdrive/htdocs/YouPHPTube-Encoder/videos/videosListToLive/192.168.1.4/watermark.png'  -filter_complex "  [0]setdar=16/9,scale=1280:720, fps=30[0:v];     [1]setdar=16/9,scale=1280:720, fps=30[1:v];     [0:v] [0:a]     [1:v] [1:a]   concat=n=2:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1 [vv] [a]; [vv][2:v]overlay=W-w-0:0[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"   -c:v libx264 -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -s 1280x720  -ar 44100   -f flv rtmp://encoder.gdrive.local/live?p=f321d14cdeeb7cded7489f504fa8862b/5fa3731d4f8a6_161
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Opening 'http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/res240/index.m3u8?token=eyJzYWx0IjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvMTkyLjE2OC4xLjRcL1lvdVBIUFR1YmVcLyIsInRva2VuVGltZU91dCI6IjIxNjAwIiwiZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJfWVBUdW5pcWlkXzVmODBjNTQ3NDIxMDU3LjI0MDU2MDE1IiwidGltZSI6MTYwNTI4MzExN30=' for reading
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[http @ 0x5627c50fa940] Opening 'http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/res360/index.m3u8?token=eyJzYWx0IjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvMTkyLjE2OC4xLjRcL1lvdVBIUFR1YmVcLyIsInRva2VuVGltZU91dCI6IjIxNjAwIiwiZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJfWVBUdW5pcWlkXzVmODBjNTQ3NDIxMDU3LjI0MDU2MDE1IiwidGltZSI6MTYwNTI4MzExN30=' for reading
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Opening 'http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/enc_5f80c54914f03.key' for reading
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Opening 'crypto+http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/res240/index0.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Opening 'http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/enc_5f80c54914f03.key' for reading
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Opening 'crypto+http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/res360/index0.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/index.m3u8?token=eyJzYWx0IjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvMTkyLjE2OC4xLjRcL1lvdVBIUFR1YmVcLyIsInRva2VuVGltZU91dCI6IjIxNjAwIiwiZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJfWVBUdW5pcWlkXzVmODBjNTQ3NDIxMDU3LjI0MDU2MDE1IiwidGltZSI6MTYwNTI4MzExN30=':
  Duration: 00:00:13.21, start: 1.460111, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 300000
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 426x240 [SAR 640:639 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 300000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 300000
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 600000
    Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 600000
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 600000
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5fa3f4e37ffb65.33430678_720.mp4?token=eyJzYWx0IjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvMTkyLjE2OC4xLjRcL1lvdVBIUFR1YmVcLyIsInRva2VuVGltZU91dCI6IjIxNjAwIiwiZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJfWVBUdW5pcWlkXzVmYTNmNGUzN2ZmYjY1LjMzNDMwNjc4IiwidGltZSI6MTYwNTI4MzExN30=':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 37 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 26 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/16/2018.
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 10/16/2018.
Input #2, png_pipe, from '/var/www/gdrive/htdocs/YouPHPTube-Encoder/videos/videosListToLive/192.168.1.4/watermark.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 3780:3780 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> setdar
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> setdar
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #2:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=50 keyint_min=5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=cbr mbtree=1 bitrate=3000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=3000 vbv_bufsize=6000 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://encoder.gdrive.local/live?p=f321d14cdeeb7cded7489f504fa8862b/5fa3731d4f8a6_161':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 3000 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 3000000/0/3000000 buffer size: 6000000 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Opening 'crypto+http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/res240/index1.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] No longer receiving playlist 1 ('http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/res360/index.m3u8?token=eyJzYWx0IjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvMTkyLjE2OC4xLjRcL1lvdVBIUFR1YmVcLyIsInRva2VuVGltZU91dCI6IjIxNjAwIiwiZmlsZW5hbWUiOiJfWVBUdW5pcWlkXzVmODBjNTQ3NDIxMDU3LjI0MDU2MDE1IiwidGltZSI6MTYwNTI4MzExN30=')
[hls @ 0x5627c50f2800] Opening 'crypto+http://192.168.1.4/YouPHPTube/videos/_YPTuniqid_5f80c547421057.24056015/res240/index2.ts' for reading
[flv @ 0x5627c52635c0] Failed to update header with correct duration.10.4kbits/s speed=1.43x
[flv @ 0x5627c52635c0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame= 1313 fps= 43 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5937kB time=00:00:43.81 bitrate=1110.1kbits/s speed=1.43x
video:5662kB audio:218kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.976283%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] frame I:70    Avg QP: 4.15  size: 27705
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] frame P:423   Avg QP: 4.16  size:  6930
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] frame B:820   Avg QP: 1.56  size:  1130
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] consecutive B-frames: 13.6%  7.9%  4.8% 73.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] mb I  I16..4: 69.2% 24.3%  6.4%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] mb P  I16..4:  2.0%  9.4%  1.6%  P16..4:  1.7%  0.3%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:85.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.3%  0.2%  B16..8:  1.0%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 0.6%  skip:97.6%  L0:57.9% L1:40.1% BI: 2.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] 8x8 transform intra:45.7% inter:71.9%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 36.1% 46.9% 43.4% inter: 0.4% 1.1% 0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 93%  4%  3%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 65%  8% 16%  1%  2%  3%  1%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 50% 20% 10%  3%  4%  5%  3%  4%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 61% 10% 25%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] ref P L0: 72.6%  2.7% 18.0%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] ref B L0: 89.1%  9.4%  1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] ref B L1: 98.0%  2.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5627c5267f40] kb/s:1059.69
[aac @ 0x5627c51d25c0] Qavg: 46028.516
avideo@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Copy and paste the complete log text.

Answer (score 0):

All attributes must be the same. In this case input #0 and input #1 have different frame rates. Make them the same with the [fps filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps).

```
ffmpeg -y -re -i "/var/www/gdrive/htdocs/YouPHPTube-Encoder/videos/videosListToLive/countdown10.mp4" -re -i "/var/www/gdrive/htdocs/YouPHPTube-Encoder/videos/videosListToLive/192.168.1.4/video_222.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=30[v0];[v0][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1:unsafe=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -c:a aac -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -f flv rtmp://encoder.gdrive.local/live?p=f321d14cdeeb7cded7489f504fa8862b/5fa3731d4f8a6_160
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer but this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @DanielSantosNeto Now you're using different inputs and those inputs have the added complexity of network protocol. It's like a whole new question. It makes it difficult to answer when each update to the question involves a new set of inputs and circumstances. Did my original answer work for the particular inputs that I addressed in the answer?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I will test your answer on the previews inputs. but By the way, there is an answer for mixed inputs with http protocol and local files?